# Why does my Batch fail to call when passed file?

Tags: batch-file

My batch file fails to implement the call command when passed a file (.mkv), but works when ran directly with no parameters. The commands after work including running vlc with arguments.

```
call "C:\Users\****\Desktop\System Tools\Monitors\Primary2.bat"

start "VLC media player.lnk" %1
```

running on windows 7 if that matters.

**update:** It seems that the call function does not want to work with primary2.bat, but will work with a much simpler batch file that does one of the things primary2.bat does

for comparison
primary2.bat

```
@ECHO off

IF Exist Single.txt (
    IF EXIST Primary1.txt (
        echo Primary Screen Set to Two >> Primary2.txt
        del /q Primary1.txt 
        echo Triple Monitors enabled >> Triple.txt
        del /q Single.txt
        If Exist HDMI.txt (
            "C:\Users\****\Desktop\System Tools\Monitors\TripleHDMI\TripleHDMI Primary2.lnk"
        )
        IF Exist VGA.txt (
            "C:\Users\****\Desktop\System Tools\Monitors\TripleVGA\TripleVGA Primary2.lnk"
        )   
    )
)

IF Exist Dual.txt (
    IF EXIST Primary1.txt (
        echo Primary Screen Set to Two >> Primary2.txt
        del /q Primary1.txt
        echo Triple Monitors enabled >> Triple.txt
        del /q Dual.txt
        If Exist HDMI.txt (
            "C:\Users\****\Desktop\System Tools\Monitors\TripleHDMI\TripleHDMI Primary2.lnk"
        )
        IF Exist VGA.txt (
            "C:\Users\****\Desktop\System Tools\Monitors\TripleVGA\TripleVGA Primary2.lnk"
        )

    )
    IF EXIST Primary3.txt (
        echo Primary Screen Set to Two >> Primary2.txt
        del /q Primary3.txt
        echo Triple Monitors enabled >> Triple.txt
        del /q Dual.txt
        If Exist HDMI.txt (
            "C:\Users\****\Desktop\System Tools\Monitors\TripleHDMI\TripleHDMI Primary2.lnk"
        )
        IF Exist VGA.txt (
            "C:\Users\****\Desktop\System Tools\Monitors\TripleVGA\TripleVGA Primary2.lnk"
        )
    )
)


IF Exist Triple.txt (
    IF EXIST Primary1.txt (
        echo Primary Screen Set to Two >> Primary2.txt
        del /q Primary1.txt
        If Exist HDMI.txt (
            "C:\Users\****\Desktop\System Tools\Monitors\TripleHDMI\TripleHDMI Primary2.lnk"
        )
        IF Exist VGA.txt (
            "C:\Users\****\Desktop\System Tools\Monitors\TripleVGA\TripleVGA Primary2.lnk"
        )
    )
    IF EXIST Primary3.txt (
        echo Primary Screen Set to Two >> Primary2.txt
        del /q Primary3.txt
        If Exist HDMI.txt (
            "C:\Users\****\Desktop\System Tools\Monitors\TripleHDMI\TripleHDMI Primary2.lnk"
        )
        IF Exist VGA.txt (
            "C:\Users\****\Desktop\System Tools\Monitors\TripleVGA\TripleVGA Primary2.lnk"
        )
    )
)
```

hello.bat used it to test, this one works

```
echo hello
"C:\Users\****\Desktop\System Tools\Monitors\TripleHDMI\TripleHDMI Primary2.lnk"
        )
pause
```

both work individually

Comment: This question makes no sense. You need to provide more explanation about what works, what doesn't work, and show your code.

Comment: Are you trying to `call file.mkv` or `call file.bat file.mkv` with the mkv file as a parameter?

Comment: a file(.mkv) is being used as the first argument of the batch script(%1), what happens when you drag a file over the .bat, the call is being made to an external .bat hence call ...\primary2.bat the call to the external .bat is not working, everything else is.

Answer (score 1):

If all you are trying to do is pass the `mkv` file as a parameter to the batch file you are calling then the syntax is

```
call "C:\Users\****\Desktop\System Tools\Monitors\Primary2.bat" mkvfile.mkv
```

Then in the calling batch file the `mkv` file will be accessible using `%1`.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out my problem. There were references to local files in the external batch file, changed them all to full addresses and now it works flawlessly.

changed HDMI.txt to "C:\Users****\Desktop\System Tools\Monitors\HDMI.txt" and so on for all addresses.

For some reason batch files that get called from cmd can't use relative addresses